# Having trouble with Distinct(Coloumn_name)

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I'm having problems with getting the correct data from my tables. 
I've got a table with information on customers sending letters.

My table have following coloumbs( Name, Postalcode, Country, Phone_number, Letters(The number of letters))

I want to get the numbers of letters send from every customer, depending on the Postal_code.

```
Select Distinct(Postal_Code), Count(*)
from Table_name    
Group by Postal_Code, Letters
```

The result of this, is not exactly what I wanted, because I get duplicates of the postalcode, and the numbers of letters are wrong. 
I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I hope someone can help me.

EDIT:

At the moment, i'm trying to get a date on the record, and my code i slike this now.

```
Select Postal_Code, Sum(Letters), To_Char(trunc(Start_time),'DD-MM-YYYY') AS StartTime
    from Table_name    
    Group by Postal_Code
```

But I get an error when running it. The error says: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.
I have googlet the problem, and tried with my start_time in the group by, but this gives me the wrong result.

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: You need to apply an aggregate function on the start_time column, e.g.: `max(start_time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GROUP BY you don't need DISTINCT. Since letters is a number you need to SUM() them. So total letters for each postal code would be something along the lines of:

```
Select Postal_Code, SUM(letters)
from Table_name    
Group by Postal_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY gives you distinct values for *all the columns* in the clause.  So grouping by POSTAL_CODE, LETTERS is why you get duplicate POSTAL_CODE values.

Not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but here is my interpretation:

```
Select Postal_Code
       , sum(letters) no_of_letters
       , Count(*) no_of_customers
from Table_name    
Group by Postal_Code
```